# Having issues with Array Splice with for loop

Tags: javascript, json

Above code splices only first element it doesn't work second time in for loop! Please help!

```
var answeredQuestions = [18,19];
var questions = [{"questionid":"18"},{"questionid":"19"},{...}];

for (var j = 0; j < questions.length; j++) {
    var pos = $.inArray(parseInt(questions[j].questionid), answeredQuestions);
    if(parseInt(pos) != -1) {
        questions.splice(j,1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you modify the array (remove items from it) in the middle of the `for` loop, it causes your `for` loop to miss items in the array.

One way to work-around that is to process the array backwards (from end to front) so that when you remove the current item from the array, you aren't messing up any of the indexes in the next iterations of the `for` loop.

```
var answeredQuestions = [18,19];
var questions = [{"questionid":"18"},{"questionid":"19"},{...}];

for (var j = questions.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    var pos = $.inArray(parseInt(questions[j].questionid, 10), answeredQuestions);
    if(pos !== -1) {
        questions.splice(j,1);
    }
}
```

Also, there is no need to use `parseInt()` on the result of `$.inArray` as it is already an integer.

---

**Edit as of 2015/2016**, it's probably easier to use `.filter()` and let that method handle the modifying of the array for you:

```
var answeredQuestions = [18,19];
var questions = [{"questionid":"18"},{"questionid":"19"},{...}];
questions = questions.filter(function(item) {
    // keep only questions that haven't been answered already
    return answeredQuestions.indexOf(+item.questionid) === -1;
});
```

Comment: ohh! didnt thought of that! perfect! let me try that out!

Comment: @jayshahagile - suggestion added.

Comment: 'j' should decrement don't you think senor?

Comment: @jayshahagile - yep, decrement.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is just filter the answered questions. You could use `.filter`:

```
var answeredQuestions = [18,19];
var questions = [{"questionid":"18"},{"questionid":"19"},{...}];

var result = questions.filter(function(e) {
  return answeredQuestions.indexOf(+e.questionid) == -1;
});
```